# match strings with numbers and letter 6 length

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to match all `SKU` codes from the following list

```
Array([0] => Array([0] => CLASSI[1] => LEATHE[2] => **0MEFCQ**))

<span>VANS CLASSIC SLIP-ON CROC LEATHER **0MEFCQ** 36-40</span>

([0] => Array([0] => TRAMPK[1] => **XH8GKA**))

<span>NOWE TRAMPKI VANS  SK8-HI SLIM ZIP **XH8GKA** 36-40</span>

([0] => Array([0] => DAMSKI[1] => TRAMPK[2] => AUTHEN[3] => **EE3W00**))

<span>DAMSKIE TRAMPKI VANS AUTHENTIC **EE3W00** 35-41</s
```

I had tried with the following `REGEX` but it returns more strings. I want only `SKU` codes.

```
preg_match_all('/[A-Z0-9]{1,2}\w{4}/', $title, $match);
```

Comment: Is the sku always the last string on a line that matches your regex?

Comment: not always.. i thought about that.. to get last match from array

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/hA9mS2/1 ?

Comment: @AlexK. what you matched is the output of my regex. I need to match from this string "VANS CLASSIC SLIP-ON CROC LEATHER 0MEFCQ 36-40"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match the SKU code you will have to match a string of length 6 with `[A-Z]`+`[0-9]`.

Try this regex.

**Regex:** `\b(?=.*\d)[A-Z0-9]{6}\b`

**Explanation:**

- `\b` on start and end checks the word boundary.
- `(?=.*\d)` checks for presence of at least one digit. Which is format of SKU Code. If present then only next 6 characters are considered as code.
- `[A-Z0-9]{6}` matches the code if previous condition is true.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mO1cC7/2)**

**[Ideone Demo](https://ideone.com/EHkWLj)**

Comment: @Kovi: I did added an explanation. Let me know what's your doubt.

Comment: but this gets other words too even without a number

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani: What's the exception ? I did added an Ideone demo and it works fine.

Comment: Note that this regex won't match SKU codes with letters only.

Comment: @FlorentB.: SKU codes are bound to have some **digits**, mentioning size or other measurements. [SKU Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stock_keeping_unit)

Comment: @Kovi: How many instances of SKU code are there in your string ? And which one should be a match ? Also explain the nature of problem it's causing.

Comment: just one.. I think I will get the last string from regex matches

Comment: @Kovi: Then I guess it's solved now. You can select the last instance of SKU code from resulting array.

Comment: @noob: from your link: "These codes are not regulated nor standardized"

Comment: @FlorentB.: Yes they are not. But most of them will have `digit` in them. And this is the case here. For SKU codes with no digits there should be some position where they appear. If you have other suggestions to improve this solution you are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

This is abit long but its just the way you want it:

```
   ([0-9]{1}[A-Z0-9]{5}|[A-Z0-9]{5}[0-9]{1}|[A-Z]{1}(?:[0-9]{1}[A-Z0-9]{3}|[A-Z0-9]{3}[0-9]{1}|[A-Z]{1}(?:[0-9]{1}[A-Z]{1}[A-Z]{1}|[0-9]{1})[A-Z]{1})[A-Z]{1})
```

Description:
Must start with a number or end with one otherwise the 4 letter in the middle must start with a number or end with one otherwise the 2 letter must start with a number or end with one

https://regex101.com/r/yY7wV8/1